# Как получить текущий символ с позиции курсора на C++ с помощью библиотеки ncurses?

Tags: c++, консоль, ncurses

Я с помощью move перемещаю курсор на определённую позицию, как получить символ с этой позиции из окна терминала?

Comment: Вопрос `ncurses get current cursor position` отсылает [сюда](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/manual/html_node/Cursor-location-and-window-coordinates.html)

Comment: chtype mvinch(int y, int x);

Comment: @Ddd Спасибо большое mvinch отлично сработал.